# Simplify Modulus Argument

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following expression (all quantities exact):$$
    \left[( 85155.86592 \cdot x + 29.714 ) \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}\right] \mod 2 \cdot \pi, ~~~~~~~~~~~x \in \mathbb{R}
$$It turns out that the magnitude of $x$ is pretty big, so there are some precision issues actually calculating this.

An improved expression can be found by premultiplying the $\pi/180$ into the other constants with high precision.  This helps, but not enough.  **How, iff possible, can I simplify the expression taking into account the modulus by $2 \pi$?**

Comment: If you only need the result $\text{mod } 2\pi$, then you can reduce every number in this equation to the smallest residue modulo $2\pi$, meaning that $85155.86592$ could be replaced with $6.138637102243933..$, same with $29..$. This will not change the end result modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt As I understand this "$\mod 2\pi$" construction, $8 \pi \mod 2\pi = 0$, but $(8-2\pi)\pi \mod 2 \pi = (8-2\pi)\pi \neq 0$, so your advice doesn't work.

Comment: You're right, not adding integer multiples but floating-point multiples of $2\pi$ destroys this. If this would be computed modulo an integer, it would have worked.